# Domain name and route53 issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, domain-name

I'm having difficulties configuring my domain through Route53. I keep getting a DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error.

My domain, oscha.jp, is registered through jp-domains.com.

I created a hosted zone in R53 and added an alias record pointing to my (test) server. I then logged into jp-domains.com and updated the nameservers to match those in R53.

Using pingdom.com DNS check tool, I have confirmed that my domain is using the correct AWS nameservers.

I have also checked the [traceroute](http://tools.pingdom.com/ping/?target=test.oscha.jp&o=1&save=true) for my alias (test.oscha.jp) and I can see that it is routing to the correct IP address. However, putting test.oscha.jp in a browser returns DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have just been checking too soon - the site resolves fine for me and it looks like it is using R53 nameservers. Maybe try from another machine/network and/or wait a while and check again.

DNS propagation happens pretty fast, but its not instantaneous.

Comment: If you are having these types of problems, try using google's DNS servers - 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 - I find that they pick up Route53 changes very quickly, usually under 5 minutes.

Comment: You can check your name servers (that should be Route 53 name servers assigned to your Hosted Zone) with https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#NS/oscha.jp and global propagation of updates with https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/oscha.jp.

Comment: I had the same problem for my website and to my surprise the site was accessible from different internet service provider but not from my ISP. May be it was just using old DNS records from the cache.

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same issue, but it wasn't a TTL issue for me. The issue I was having was that I had deleted my Hosted Zone and created a new one with what I thought were the same settings. However, I hadn't copied over my new NS addresses (I also have the domain registered through AWS), so the domain was still pointing to the old ones.

If this is the case, also make sure to go into **Registered Domains** (if you also have your address registered through AWS) or wherever else you have your name server configuration in the service you do have your domain registered.